# How does this definition about maps make sense?

Tags: general-topology

This definition is in chapter 46 of munkres. It is in the chapter of pointwise and compact convergence. And it is in the end of the chapter after he has talked about the compact-open topology. He makes this definition:

> Definition: Given a function $f : X\times Z \rightarrow Y$, there is a corresponding function $F : Z \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$,
>   defined by the equation:
>
> $(F(z))(x)=f(x,z)$.
>
> Conversly, given $F : Z \rightarrow \mathcal{C}(X,Y)$, this equation
>   defines a corresponding function  $f: X \times Z \rightarrow Y$. We say
>   that F is the map of Z into $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ that is induced by f.

My question is regarding the first part of the definition. When he has the function f, and given z, how does he know that the resulting function $h(x)=f(x,z)$ is in $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$?, I mean, it is a function from X to Y, but how do we know it is continuous?

Comment: We can show that if $f:X×Z\to Y$ is a continuous map, then the function $F:Z\to C(X,Y)$ defined by $F(z)(x)=f(x,z)$ is well-defined, i.e. the function $F(z):X\to Y$ is continuous.

This is simply because $F(z)$ can be composed as $f\circ i_z$ where $i_z:X\to X×Z$ is the map $x\mapsto (x,z)$.

Moreover, since $C(X,Y)$ carries a topology, we can check the map $F$ for continuity. It turns out that $F$ is continuous as well.

However, given a continuous $F:Z\to C(X,Y)$, the corresponding $f:X×Z\times Y$ need not be continuous. So I'm not sure, in which cases he assumes *functions* to be continuous